# Can BindProperty extract data from posted JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core has this [BindProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.bindpropertyattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0) attribute that you can use to bind controller-level properties to parameters of HTTP request.

```
[BindProperty (SupportsGet=true)]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

However, it does not bind to the request, if it's `Content-Type: application.json` and the body is:

```
{
    "name": "Somebody"
}
```

Can we configure it to bind to JSON too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Request body needs to bind a complex model, So you can't bind `string` directly, If you want to bind this value, Here are two methods.

The first method is to create a class include this property:

```
public class Test
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Then bind this class in your code:

```
    [BindProperty]
    [FromBody]
    public Test test { get; set; }
```

The second method is custom model binding:

```
public class MyBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            if (bindingContext == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));

            var modelName = bindingContext.FieldName;

            string bodyAsText = await new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            if (bodyAsText == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            
            //check if the key equals fieldName
            var key = bodyAsText.Trim().Substring(12, modelName.Length);
            if (!modelName.Equals(key))
            {
                return;
            }

            //get the value.
            var result = bodyAsText.Split(":")[1];
            var a = result.Substring(2, result.IndexOf("\r") - 3);

            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(a);
        }
    }
```

Then you can bind a string value:

```
[BindProperty]
[ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(MyBinder))]
public string Name { get; set; }
```